# Angular. Как настроить прокси для localhost:4200/meeting --> localhost:4200?

Tags: angular

Сервер развёртывается с контекстом meeting
В index.html добавлен

```
<base href="/meeting/">
```

Содержимое файла:
proxy-config.json

```
{
  "/meeting": {
    "target": "localhost:4200",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Запускаю так:

```
ng serve --open --proxy-config proxy-config.json
```

По логам видно, что прокси создаётся

```
Proxy created: /meeting  ->  localhost:4200,
```

но ресурсы всё равно недоступны

```
Error occurred while trying to proxy request /meeting/polyfills.js from localhost:4200 to localhost:4200 (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Comment: ты неправильно используешь прокси, если твой сервер стартует на 4200 - у тебя прокси проксирует запросы опять же на 4200, в `target` должен быть другой порт - т.е. куда проксировать

Comment: у меня проблема не в порте, у меня проблема в контексте meeting

Comment: зачем тебе такой base href + proxy?

Comment: Нет идей больше как сделать. На сервере жёстко закреплён контекст server.servlet.context-path=/meeting

Comment: а что сервер отдает по этому урлу? статика? просто джсон?

Comment: Конкретно по этому - ничего. Это контекст. Он добавляется автоматически ко всем точкам входа. Если скажем сервер ловит запросы по api/car, api/bath, то при добавлении контекста meeting ловит по meeting/api/car, meeting/api/bath

Comment: а не легче ли тебе было бы просто создать перехватчик который бы к каждому запросу добавлял префикс `meeting/api`?

Comment: собственно так и сделано <base href="/meeting/">

Comment: просто не работает, когда запускаешь как ng serve --open. пока нашёл такое решение: ng serve --open --base-href=/

Comment: бейз ашреф это не перехватчик, я имею в виду `HttpInterceptor`

Comment: проблемы возникнут, если будет просто роутинг внутри клиента